# Obter os dados de uma coluna criada

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma tabela com 4 campos e através deles faço alguns cálculos e crio um novo campo para mostrar esses mesmos resultados... O problema é que depois quero ir buscar esses resultados e não sei como os consigo resgatar.

```
declare @mesAtual as int = (6)
        
        select  mes, 
                valor, 
                periodicidade , 
                cast(valor / periodicidade as decimal(18,2)) as ValorMes,
                case when @mesAtual > mes then @mesAtual - mes
                when @mesAtual < mes then (periodicidade - (mes - @mesAtual)) + 1
                when @mesAtual = mes then 0 end as Diferenca
                
        from tblPrevista
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sugiro que você cole na pergunta o código da sua consulta SQL além da imagem, assim quem for te ajudar pode copiar a consulta com mais facilidade.

Comment: Tem toda a razão, obrigado pela sugestão. @Ana Carolina Manzan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma de resolver o problema seria pegar essa sua query e jogar dentro de uma subquery, e então selecionar estes campos que você deseja "por fora". Ficaria assim:

```
declare @mesAtual as int = (6)

SELECT  *,
        ValorMes * Diferenca as Final
FROM  
(SELECT mes, 
        valor,
        periodicidade,
        cast(valor/periodicidade as decimal(18,2)) as ValorMes,
        CASE 
        WHEN @mesAtual > mes then @mesAtual - mes
        WHEN @mesAtual < mes then (periodicidade - (mes - @mesAtual)) + 1
        WHEN @mesAtual = mes then 0 end as Diferenca
 FROM tblPrevista) as tblPrevistaCalculos
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, esta resposta me ajudou muito.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, e se fizesse assim:
select  mes,
valor,
periodicidade ,
(cast(valor / periodicidade as decimal(18,2)) *

```
            (case when @mesAtual > mes then @mesAtual - mes
            when @mesAtual < mes then (periodicidade - (mes - @mesAtual)) + 
            1
            when @mesAtual = mes then 0 end)) as final

    from tblPrevista
```

só multiplicando direto (sem subquery), poderíamos tentar evitar as subqueries, nada contra elas mas vocês já viram como fica depois de anos de alterações em sistemas comerciais? um excesso de subqueries e selects por fora,fica muito grande e difícil de dar manutenção, espero ter ajudado